# vichuploader image not uploaded + image name is null

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, vichuploaderbundle

I want to use vichuploader to manage image upload on my Symfony 5.4 project. I got the image_name cannot be null SQL error but can't find why... The mapping naming is good the updateAt field is filled. I don't see anything. Thanks for your help.

Here is my code :

*vich_uploader.yml*

```
vich_uploader:
db_driver: orm

mappings:
    images:
        uri_prefix:         /uploads/images
        upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/images'
        namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\SmartUniqueNamer
```

*Entity handling 3 image entity*

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\BabyStuffRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use App\Entity\Trait\MetaDataTrait;
use Symfony\Component\String\Slugger\SluggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

#[ApiResource()]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: BabyStuffRepository::class)]
#[ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks]
class BabyStuff
{
use MetaDataTrait;

#[ORM\Id]
#[ORM\GeneratedValue]
#[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
private $id;

#[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
#[Assert\NotBlank]
private ?string $title = null;

#[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
#[Assert\NotBlank]
private ?string $description = null;

#[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
#[Assert\NotBlank]
private ?string $city = null;

#[ORM\Column(length: 100, nullable: true)]
#[Assert\NotBlank]
#[Assert\Country]
private ?string $country = null;

#[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'babyStuffs')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
private ?User $user = null;

#[ORM\Column(length: 50, nullable: true)]
#[Assert\NotBlank]
private ?string $state = null;

#[ORM\Column]
#[Assert\NotBlank]
#[Assert\PositiveOrZero]
private ?float $price = null;

#[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'babystuff')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
#[Assert\NotBlank]
private ?Category $category = null;

#[ORM\Column]
private ?bool $isOnHome = null;

#[ORM\OneToOne(cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
#[Assert\NotNull]
private ?Image $image1 = null;

#[ORM\OneToOne(cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
private ?Image $image2 = null;

#[ORM\OneToOne(cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
private ?Image $image3 = null;

private $slugger;

public function __construct(/* SluggerInterface $slugger */)
{
    /* $this->slugger = $slugger; */
}

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getTitle(): ?string
{
    return $this->title;
}

public function getSlugTitle(): string
{
    return $this->slugger->slug($this->title);
}

public function setTitle(string $title): self
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

public function getDescription(): ?string
{
    return $this->description;
}

public function setDescription(string $description): self
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

public function getCity(): ?string
{
    return $this->city;
}

public function setCity(?string $city): self
{
    $this->city = $city;

    return $this;
}

public function getCountry(): ?string
{
    return $this->country;
}

public function setCountry(?string $country): self
{
    $this->country = $country;

    return $this;
}

public function getUser(): ?User
{
    return $this->user;
}

public function setUser(?User $user): self
{
    $this->user = $user;

    return $this;
}

public function getState(): ?string
{
    return $this->state;
}

public function setState(?string $state): self
{
    $this->state = $state;

    return $this;
}

public function getPrice(): ?float
{
    return $this->price;
}

public function setPrice(float $price): self
{
    $this->price = $price;

    return $this;
}

public function getCategory(): ?Category
{
    return $this->category;
}

public function setCategory(?Category $category): self
{
    $this->category = $category;

    return $this;
}

public function isIsOnHome(): ?bool
{
    return $this->isOnHome;
}

public function setIsOnHome(bool $isOnHome): self
{
    $this->isOnHome = $isOnHome;

    return $this;
}

public function getImage1(): ?Image
{
    return $this->image1;
}

public function setImage1(Image $image1): self
{
    $this->image1 = $image1;

    return $this;
}

public function getImage2(): ?Image
{
    return $this->image2;
}

public function setImage2(?Image $image2): self
{
    $this->image2 = $image2;

    return $this;
}

public function getImage3(): ?Image
{
    return $this->image3;
}

public function setImage3(?Image $image3): self
{
    $this->image3 = $image3;

    return $this;
}
}
```

*my Image entity*

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\ImageRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ImageRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource]
#[Vich\Uploadable]
class Image
{
#[ORM\Id]
#[ORM\GeneratedValue]
#[ORM\Column]
private ?int $id = null;

#[Vich\UploadableField(mapping: 'images', fileNameProperty: 'imageName')]
private ?File $imageFile = null;

#[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
private ?string $imageName = null;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime')]
private $updatedAt;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getImageFile(): ?string
{
    return $this->imageFile;
}

/**
 * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile|null $imageFile
 */
public function setImageFile(?File $imageFile = null): void
{
    $this->imageFile = $imageFile;

    if (null !== $imageFile) {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTimeImmutable();
    }
}

public function getImageName(): ?string
{
    return $this->imageName;
}

public function setImageName(string $imageName): self
{
    $this->imageName = $imageName;

    return $this;
}

public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
{
    return $this->updatedAt;
}

public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
{
    $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

    return $this;
}

}
```

*My main form type*

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\BabyStuff;
use App\Entity\Category;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CountryType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\MoneyType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;

class BabyStuffType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Titre de l\'annonce'],
            ])
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control no-height', 'placeholder' => 'Description', 'rows' => 5],
            ])
            ->add('category', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Category::class,
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                        ->where('c.isOnline = true')
                        ->orderBy('c.title', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'title',
                'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Catégorie'],
            ])
            ->add('state', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices'  => [
                    'Neuf' => 'NEW',
                    'Bon état' => 'GOOD',
                    'Etat satisfaisant' => 'USED',
                ],
                'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Etat'],
            ])
            ->add('price', NumberType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Prix/jour'],
            ])
            ->add('city', TextType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Ville'],
            ])
            ->add('country', CountryType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Pays'],
            ])
            ->add('image1', ImageType::class)
            ->add('image2', ImageType::class, [
                'required' => false,
            ])
            ->add('image3', ImageType::class, [
                'required' => false,
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => BabyStuff::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

*My Image form type*

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Image;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichImageType;

class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('imageFile', VichImageType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'delete_label' => 'Supprimer',
                'download_label' => 'Télécharger',
                'download_uri' => true,
                'image_uri' => true,
                /* 'imagine_pattern' => 'product_photo_320x240', */
                'asset_helper' => true,
                'label' => false
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Image::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found out what was the problem... I'm using Attributes instead of Annotations and for some reasons Vich don't work with Attributes on my env. Changing to Annotations made things work.